# string::compare superfluous parameter?

Tags: c++, stl

In the [C++ reference on `string::compare`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/), there is the following overload:

```
int compare ( size_t pos1, size_t n1, const string& str, size_t pos2, size_t n2 ) const;
```

which has two parameters `n1` and `n2` which in my eyes should always be equal or the function returns an `int` equal to `true` (string::compare return value of 0 (false) signifies equal strings). Is this correct? If not, could you provide an example showing a specific case where the comparison would be `false` if unequal lengths (`n1 != n2`) are compared?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, an `int` equal to `false` ?

Comment: @icecrime: an `int` can be easily converted to a `bool`, this is how you can use `if` with `strcmp` and the like for example.

Comment: Yes, but like `strcmp`, `compare` does not return a boolean value, but rather an integer (like it says). For equal strings `compare` returns an integer value of 0, which evaluates to `false` in boolean context.

Comment: @eq: ok, my mistake, but string equality can be tested by `a.compare(b)` nonetheless.

Comment: @ruvenb: just shaved such use from a code I was using this week, it certainly is not as clear as `a == b`, thus I really feel `compare` is better used when you actually care for ordering.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: So you would recommend using `string::substring` and `operator==` over `string::compare`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `n1` and `n2` parameters are the **maximum** number of characters to compare. The std::compare function will trim the values if they exceed the length of the strings. Here is an example where the values aren't equal and the function returns 0.

```
std::string a("AACAB");
std::string b("CAB");
std::cout << a.compare(2, 8, b, 0, 12) << '\n';
```

I'm not sure when this is useful but there is the specific case you asked for.

Answer (score 8):

> in my eyes should always be equal or
>   the function returns an int equal to
>   false

Compare is a tri-valued comparison: negative/zero/positive are the significant kinds of return value rather than just true/false. It returns an int equal to false if the strings *are* equal, not if they aren't.

If you're lexically ordering (sub)strings of different lengths, `compare` will tell you what order they come.

If all you care about is (sub)string equality, then different lengths implies not equal. As an optimization, you could skip calling `compare` if `n1 != n2`.

Answer (score 1):

One documentation says:
"Return Value: A negative value if the operand string is less than the parameter string; zero if the two strings are equal; or a positive value if the operand string is greater than the parameter string."

So its just not true or false.
e.g.

Operand: "abc", Parameter: "ab" Returns: -1

Operand: "abc", Parameter: "ad" Returns: +1